# google renewable subscriptions abuse

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

we have an application that utilizes auto renewable subscriptions in android.

The users are going subscribing through the app normally and the receipt is sent for our backend to be validated using the IAP Google API.

until this point everything is fine, but we recently discovred a loophole in our system, some users are subscribe and cancel their subscriptions and re-enable the auto subscription, this way google will issues a new receipt that is sent to our backend and we are giving them another year, this is easily solved by granting the only the duration given in the receipt

but then users started using the same google account with different accounts for our apps and they give everyone free subscriptions by the generated receipt

I read the API in here and I can't find any field that tells us that this receipt is only a re-activation not a new subscription
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions

when we send a request for google api to get the info this is what we are getting:

```
status_from_google_play
{
    "autoRenewing": true,
    "cancelReason": null,
    "countryCode": "SA",
    "developerPayload": "",
    "expiryTimeMillis": "1534073485784",
    "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
    "linkedPurchaseToken": "sometoken",
    "orderId": "GPA.xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx",
    "paymentState": 1,
    "priceAmountMicros": "290000",
    "priceCurrencyCode": "SAR",
    "purchaseType": 0,
    "startTimeMillis": "1534071687580",
    "userCancellationTimeMillis": null
}
```

There is no field that gives me this piece of information

am I missing something? is there another way to validate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the `linkedPurchaseToken` field can be used for this purpose
if the linked token is not empty it means it's a *re-activation only* or an *upgrade/downgrade* for the subscription.

It's not a direct usage as you can see but it's how you know.

Comment: I'm running into similar problem. What did you end up doing? I'm thinking to look up the linked token and use the original transaction id instead of the new transaction id given by Google with the new token. Do you see any problem with that logic?

Comment: I don't remember the exact solution I went for, it's been a while, but basically any receipt we get with a none-null linkedPurchaseToken is ignored, for example some one subscribed for a year, canceled and then subscribed again, I don't need to do anything here, just ignore the second receipt